# Modificar números enteros de una lista a cadena

Tags: python

Tengo una función llamada `"def lectura()"` la cual tiene una lista variada de productos junto a dos precios, uno **"econónimo"** y otro **"premium"**. Lo que debo hacer es llamar a esa función dentro de otra `"def buscar_producto(lista_productos)"` y luego elegir una al azar, que ya lo tengo:

```
def buscar_producto(lista_productos):
    lista_productos = lectura()
    producto_r = random.choice(lista_productos)

    return producto_r
```

Mi tema ahora es que, de ese producto elegido al azar, debo modificarlo para que me muestre si ese producto es **económico** o **premium**, tal que me quede algo así:

Producto elegido al azar de ejemplo: **['Escritorio', 2030, 3717]**

```
>>>
# En caso de ser Premium
['Escritorio', 'Premium', 3717]
>>>
# En caso de ser Económico
['Escritorio','Económico', 2030]
```

Comment: Hay algo que no queda claro, afirmas: "para que me muestre si ese producto es económico o premium", pero ¿que indica si se debe escoger la versión  económica o premium del producto, y por tanto cual de los dos precios elegir? ¿O también se debe eligir aleatoriamente cual de los dos precios del producto retornar? ¿O acaso tu función debe retornar las dos listas con ambas opciones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

después de uq ehayas obtenido el producto elegido al azar, se obtienen los precios economicos y premiun del producto utilizando los índices 1 y 2. después comparas el precio economico con el precio premiun para determinar si el producto es economico o premiun. e insertas la rtiqueta que le corresponde en la posición 1 de la lista del producto elegido al azar utilizando el metodo insert() y esto servira para modificar el producto para que muestre si es economico o premiun.

```
def buscar_producto(lista_productos):
    lista_productos = lectura()
    producto_r = random.choice(lista_productos)

    
    indice_producto = lista_productos.index(producto_r)

    
    precio_economico = producto_r[1]
    precio_premium = producto_r[2]

    
    if precio_economico < precio_premium:
        producto_r.insert(1, 'Económico')
    else:
        producto_r.insert(1, 'Premium')

    return producto_r
```

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias, me sucede igual que se imprimen los dos precios(eso ya lo solucione con un .pop) pero con el "if" siempre el primer valor va ser el menor, entonces siempre se va a imprimir que es económico ¿como lo soluciono?